# Redirect user to his last visited page after session ends and relogin

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am trying to implement an option that when a user times out, after he logs in again, he is redirected to the previous page he was in. The problem I seem to have is that I can't get the url of the page when session ends.
I tried something like:

```
protected void Session_end(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    Application["userUrl"] = userUrl;
}
```

and on session start check if the url exists and redirect to it.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
        {
            string userUrl = Application["userUrl"].ToString();
        }
        catch
        {}
}
```

The error i get is 'Request is not available in this context' on `string userUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`
. Can anyone please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In each page load you should store the username and url in some persistent store.  Then when a new session starts lookup the url for the username and redirect the client to this page.

Answer (score 0):

In Session_End(), if you want to access Request object, need to access it through HttpContext.Current.Request

However as far as I know, if you use Form Authentication, when session ends, by default FormAuthenticationModule will redirect you to login page with returnUrl as query string in url. In login page, you can just check for that parameter and do the redirection after authentication is successful.